# What to do when something offensive in chat is edited into something not offensive before it is seen

Tags: support, chat, flags

I went into a chat room, and someone said something offensive to me. So I flagged it as offensive. Almost immediately, the chat message was edited into something nicer. When the 10k-ers came into the chat room, the message was already edited into something nicer, so they could not see the offensive message. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Flag for moderator and explain what happened in the text box?

Comment: Room owners and mods can see the message history, i.e. what it looked like before.

Comment: You can view the history of a message, so that can be used as proof

Comment: @Adám I think anyone can, for non-deleted messages

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Right, but only ROs and mods are relevant here, and I wanted to cover the case where the msg is "edited" away, i.e. deleted.

Comment: @pxeger It says I have already flagged.

Comment: I'll add on a comment since I am the one who declined your flag - I apologize for not checking the history first. Since I mentioned to not flag things that aren't offensive, I would appreciate if you just tell me (in that room or TNB or wherever) what happened since I simply made a mistake and forgot to check. The message has been retroactively flagged in the trash now though; my apologies.

Comment: or if you don't want to publicly mention it, a mod flag with an explanation is probably better. i'll remember to manually check the history in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, the full history of a (non-deleted) message can be seen by all users. Additionally, room owners and moderators can see the history of any messages, deleted or not. Therefore, you're always able to point to the message to provide proof to a moderator for the fact that something offensive was said.

This is an appropriate time to flag a message for moderator support. If you click the drop-down arrow on the lefthand side of a message, you'll see this pop-up:

[image: message action pop-up]

See at the bottom is the option to "flag for moderator". Unlike flagging as spam/offensive, this option allows you to briefly describe the problem to a moderator, so they can handle it. Additionally, these flags are only shown to diamond moderators, rather than to any user with 10k reputation in chat.

Here, flag the edited message for moderator, explain briefly what happened (e.g. link to this meta question) and they'll take the appropriate actions (such as deleting the message, or purging the revision history etc.)

Comment: Purging is generally saved for redacting things that shouldn't be public even to ROs / mods, just as side note - such as private information, or stuff that was supposed to be posted in a mod room but was posted in the wrong place...